# How to add custom field in Customer admin and process that data

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I want to add custom field in Customer admin and i need to process some operations but those operations should not to save in database.

I am following this tutorial https://webkul.com/blog/tab-with-form-in-admin-customer-edit-magento-2-0/

But not able to figure it out. i don't know how to get that data ?. Also in this code while initialise `$this->initForm();` data is not posted from this form.

Also not able to figure it out where `$rowcom` is coming from .

Any help would be helpful .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change class following way:

```
namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Block\Adminhtml\Customer\Edit;

use Magento\Customer\Controller\RegistryConstants;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Layout\Tabs\TabInterface;
use Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form;
use Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Generic;
/**
 * Customer account form block
 */
class Tabs extends Generic implements TabInterface
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\System\Store
     */
    protected $_systemStore;
    /**
     * Core registry
     *
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Registry
     */
    protected $_coreRegistry;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\FormFactory $formFactory,
        \Magento\Store\Model\System\Store $systemStore,

        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_coreRegistry = $registry;
        $this->_systemStore = $systemStore;
        parent::__construct($context, $registry, $formFactory, $data);
    }

    /**
     * @return string|null
     */
    public function getCustomerId()
    {
        return $this->_coreRegistry->registry(RegistryConstants::CURRENT_CUSTOMER_ID);
    }

    /**
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Phrase
     */
    public function getTabLabel()
    {
        return __('Demo Tab');
    }

    /**
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Phrase
     */
    public function getTabTitle()
    {
        return __('Demo Tab');
    }

    /**
     * @return bool
     */
    public function canShowTab()
    {
        if ($this->getCustomerId()) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isHidden()
    {
        if ($this->getCustomerId()) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Tab class getter
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getTabClass()
    {
        return '';
    }

    /**
     * Return URL link to Tab content
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getTabUrl()
    {
        return '';
    }

    /**
     * Tab should be loaded trough Ajax call
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isAjaxLoaded()
    {
        return false;
    }
    public function initForm()
    {
        if (!$this->canShowTab()) {
            return $this;
        }
        /**@var \Magento\Framework\Data\Form $form */
        $form = $this->_formFactory->create();
        $form->setHtmlIdPrefix('myform_');

        $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('base_fieldset', ['legend' => __('Fields Information')]);

        $fieldset->addField(
            'demo_field',
            'text',
            [
                'name' => 'demo_field',
                'data-form-part' => $this->getData('target_form'),
                'label' => __('Demo Field in Customer Section'),
                'title' => __('Demo Field in Customer Section')
            ]
        );
        $this->setForm($form);
        return $this;
    }
    /**
     * @return string
     */
    protected function _toHtml()
    {
        if ($this->canShowTab()) {
            $this->initForm();
            return parent::_toHtml();
        } else {
            return '';
        }
    }
}
```

Make sure **namespace** match your module.

After that you can able to get this field value by

```
/** @var \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request */
$request = $this->getRequest();
$originalRequestData = $request->getPostValue();
echo $originalRequestData['demo_field'];
```

I have test this M2.2

**[Update]**

Create a plugin for getting data during save.

**VendorName/ModuleName/etc/adminhtml/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Customer\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Save">
        <plugin name="sr_customer_save" type="VendorName\ModuleName\Plugin\Customer\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Save" sortOrder="1"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

VendorName/ModuleName/Plugin/Customer/Controller/Adminhtml/Index/Save.php

```
namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Plugin\Customer\Controller\Adminhtml\Index;

class Save
{
    public function afterExecute(
        \Magento\Customer\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Save $subject,
        $result
    ) {
        $demoField = $subject->getRequest()->getParam('demo_field');
        error_log($demoField);
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where should I put this code then

Comment: Check updated answer

Comment: Hi @SohelRana, I have tried this code. but when save customer I can't get any params of the custom field. Can you please help me?

Comment: @RP, I know it's late. But it might help others if they will find the same issue as you and i got. You just need to add this line of code in the in your custom field along with other parameters in the array. 'data-form-part' => $this->getData('target_form')